# Sqoop import from SQL Server with Kerberos Authentication

Tags: sql-server, kerberos, sqoop

I am trying to import some data from SQL Server with Kerberos Authentication using Sqoop 1.4.5 but I am getting some authentication errors as follows. I already have a Kerberos ticket granted to my user.

```
15/11/11 14:13:46 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.5-cdh5.4.2
15/11/11 14:13:46 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
15/11/11 14:13:46 INFO tool.BaseSqoopTool: Using Hive-specific delimiters for output. You can override
15/11/11 14:13:46 INFO tool.BaseSqoopTool: delimiters with --fields-terminated-by, etc.
15/11/11 14:13:46 INFO teradata.TeradataManagerFactory: Loaded connector factory for 'Cloudera Connector Powered by Teradata' on version 1.4c5
15/11/11 14:13:46 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
15/11/11 14:13:46 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
15/11/11 14:13:48 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: XXXXX ;
15/11/11 14:13:48 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: XXXXX ;
15/11/11 14:13:48 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hadoop-mapreduce
Note: ./tmp/XXXXX/QueryResult.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
15/11/11 14:13:50 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: ./tmp/XXXXX/QueryResult.jar
15/11/11 14:13:50 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Beginning query import.
15/11/11 14:13:50 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar
15/11/11 14:13:50 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
15/11/11 14:13:51 INFO hdfs.DFSClient: Created HDFS_DELEGATION_TOKEN token 42791 for saitoped on ha-hdfs:nameservice1
15/11/11 14:13:51 INFO security.TokenCache: Got dt for hdfs://nameservice1; Kind: HDFS_DELEGATION_TOKEN, Service: ha-hdfs:nameservice1, Ident: (HDFS_DELEGATION_TOKEN token 42791 for saitoped)
15/11/11 14:13:54 INFO db.DBInputFormat: Using read commited transaction isolation
15/11/11 14:13:54 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
15/11/11 14:13:54 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1447260428787_0025
15/11/11 14:13:54 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Kind: HDFS_DELEGATION_TOKEN, Service: ha-hdfs:nameservice1, Ident: (HDFS_DELEGATION_TOKEN token 42791 for saitoped)
15/11/11 14:13:55 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1447260428787_0025
15/11/11 14:13:55 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: https://XXXXX/proxy/application_1447260428787_0025/
15/11/11 14:13:55 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1447260428787_0025
15/11/11 14:14:04 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1447260428787_0025 running in uber mode : false
15/11/11 14:14:04 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
15/11/11 14:14:28 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1447260428787_0025_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Integrated authentication failed. ClientConnectionId:312f6965-4044-4a25-bb99-619272faf085
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.setConf(DBInputFormat.java:167)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:73)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:749)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Integrated authentication failed. ClientConnectionId:312f6965-4044-4a25-bb99-619272faf085
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.getConnection(DBInputFormat.java:220)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.setConf(DBInputFormat.java:165)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Integrated authentication failed. ClientConnectionId:312f6965-4044-4a25-bb99-619272faf085
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:1667)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.KerbAuthentication.intAuthInit(KerbAuthentication.java:176)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.KerbAuthentication.GenerateClientContext(KerbAuthentication.java:268)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:2691)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:2234)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:41)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:2220)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1326)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:991)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBConfiguration.getConnection(DBConfiguration.java:302)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.getConnection(DBInputFormat.java:213)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.KerbAuthentication.getClientCredential(KerbAuthentication.java:199)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.KerbAuthentication.intAuthInit(KerbAuthentication.java:150)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential.getInstance(Krb5InitCredential.java:147)
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getCredentialElement(Krb5MechFactory.java:121)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.getCredentialElement(GSSManagerImpl.java:192)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSCredentialImpl.add(GSSCredentialImpl.java:406)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSCredentialImpl.<init>(GSSCredentialImpl.java:60)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.createCredential(GSSManagerImpl.java:153)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.KerbAuthentication$1.run(KerbAuthentication.java:189)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.KerbAuthentication$1.run(KerbAuthentication.java:187)
        ... 29 more
```

Bellow is my Sqoop string

```
sqoop import 
--connect $JDBC_URL  
--username $JDBC_USER  
--password *** 
--bindir ./tmp/$DATABASE_NAME/$DESTINE_TABLE 
--outdir ./tmp/$DATABASE_NAME/$DESTINE_TABLE 
--query $QUERY $HIVE_CMD 
--hive-import 
--hive-table=$DATABASE_NAME.$DESTINE_TABLE 
--hive-overwrite 
--hive-drop-import-delims 
--target-dir /$ENVIRONMENT/edl/infra/...
```

Any idea on how I can solve that?

Answer (score -1):

The error message states that **Microsoft** SQL Server ignores your user/password parameters because it expects "single-sign-on" with an implicit **Microsoft-compliant** (i.e. SSPI) Kerberos ticket -- the kind produced by **Microsoft** Active Directory for **Microsoft** Windows.

But Hadoop uses **Java-compliant** (i.e. GSSAPI) Kerberos tickets. These do not work for Skull Server.

And anyway you probably don't want to use "single-sign-on" since you provide a user/password on the Sqoop command line!

So the short answer is: edit the JDBC URL to remove the `integratedsecurity=true` stuff that probably lurks there. And pleaaaaaase read some SQL Server documentation.

Comment: Thanks Samson. The point is that wouldn't like to provide user/password via Sqoop command line and that is why I am trying to make it work with Kerberos Authentication.

Comment: Then look at the Sqoop documentation about arguments `password-file` or *(with Sqoop 1.4.5+ on Hadoop 2.6+)* `--password-alias`  http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_connecting_to_a_database_server

Comment: For the `hadoop credentials` admin command: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/CommandsManual.html#credential